# Make printf print only the first x bytes of an n-byte integer

Tags: c, printf

I'm creating a function that breaks up a 64-bit integer into its IEEE 754 floating-point parts (biased exponent, significand, etc.). I'd like to display the biased exponent in only 3 characters, but I'm pretty new to C, so I'm having trouble getting it below 8 characters. What  formatting specification do I have to give printf to achieve this? By the way, I can only use printf from the library, and can't convert to strings or anything like that.

So for example, if the integer is `0x4014000000000000`, I'd like to display just `401`.

Comment: Are you trying to find a printf syntax that will isolate the exponent of a number, or are you just having trouble setting the precision with which the exponent is printed?

Comment: I've already extracted the exponent and stored it in an unsigned long long int, I'd just like to figure out how to display it in only 3 characters, since that's all that's needed.

Comment: So you just want the 11 bits of the exponent? is that correct ? And somehow you want the expressed as three *characters* ?? I'm confused. Sry.

Comment: WhozCraig My choice of "character" was poor. I've updated my question to better reflect what I'd like.

Comment: It's a 64-bit *unsigned* integer, right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming unsigned type!

You can't specify bytes of an int to print in the format string of printf. But you can shift the value being printer by an amount of bits.

```
printf("Number %d", 0xFF000000) // outputs 4278190080
printf("Number %d", 0xFF000000 >> 24) // outputs 255
```

edit: so the number you got is 0x4014000000000000, then it will be

```
printf("Number %d", 0x4014000000000000 >> 52)
```

Comment: Just be careful with right shifting signed integers (the OP never stated they are unsigned).

Comment: Like GWW said: to prevent sign extension you should mask the value: `printf("Number %X", (0x4014000000000000 >> 52) & 0xFFF);`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah no need for an AND, just `0x4014000000000000ULL >> 52` is enough. If it's a variable, cast it to unsigned `(unsigned long long)x >> 52`

Comment: My printf prints the value in hex, then decimal. If I say `printf("hex: %x, decimal: %d", value >> 52, value);`, then the decimal displays correctly (1025), but the hex value shows up as 0. Why is this?

Comment: @spartanhooah. You seem to have forgotten the shift right for the second parameter. I assume the arguments can only be max 32bits on your system, and hence shows 0.

Try:
printf("hex: %x, decimal: %d", value >> 52, value >> 52);